# WaitForMultipleObjects access violation when writing

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, winapi, access-violation

I have read the question that was posted earlier that seemed to be having the same error that I am getting when using wait for multiple objects but I believe that mine is different.  I am using several threads to compute different parts of a mandelbrot set.  The program compiles and produces the correct result about 3 out of 5 times but sometimes I get an error that says "Access violation when writing to ... (some memory location that is different every time)".  Like I said, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  I put break points before and after the waitformultipleobjects and have concluded that that must be the culprit.  I just dont know why.  Here is the code...

```
int max = size();
if (max == 0)               //Return false if there are no threads
    return false;

for(int i=0;i<max;++i)          //Resume all threads
    ResumeThread(threads[i]);

HANDLE *first = &threads[0];    //Create a pointer to the first thread
WaitForMultipleObjects(max,first,TRUE,INFINITE);//Wait for all threads to finish
```

Update: I tried using a for loop and WaitForSingleObject and the problem still persisted.
Update 2: Here is the thread function.  It looks kind of ugly with all of the pointers.

```
unsigned MandelbrotSet::tfcn(void* obj)
{
funcArg *args = (funcArg*) obj;
int count = 0;
vector<int> dummy;

while(args->set->counts.size() <= args->row)
{
        args->set->counts.push_back(dummy);
}
for(int y = 0; y < args->set->nx; ++y)
{

    complex<double> c(args->set->zCorner.real() + (y * args->set->dx), args->set->zCorner.imag() + (args->row * args->set->dy));
    count = args->set->iterate(c);
    args->set->counts[args->row].push_back(count);
}
return 0;
}
```

Resolved: Alright everyone, I found the issue.  You were right.  It was in the thread itself.  The problem was that all of the threads were trying to add rows to my 2D vector of counts (counts.push_back(dummy)).  I guess the race condition was taking effect and each thread assumed it should add more rows even when it wasn't necessary.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are not close, no writing takes place in this snippet.

Comment: I hope you don't call SuspendThread anywhere. That may cause you trouble. Anyway, I think the problem is in working thread's code, but you see main thread waiting in WFMO, like it very well should be.

Comment: bug liable to be inside threads rather than outside

Comment: When I use the debugger it says that the break point was in a file called xutility.  Its in a function called _Container_base12::_Swap_all

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  I edited the question and stated what was wrong but I will do it again here.  I was encountering the race condition when I tried to push a vector of complex numbers to the 2D vector in my thread function.  This is controlled by the while loop and when each thread is executed, each thread believes that it needs to push more vector to the 2D vector called counts.  I moved this loop to the constructor and simply push all of the necessary vectors onto counts upon creation.  Thanks for helping me look in a different direction!